# Processing a sub report based on a condition in Acumatica,

Tags: acumatica, subreport

I have a report that reads Sales orders and Invoices, but some orders are Drop Ships, I have created a sub report to retrieve some values and it was working fine until February, it seems this month has a more records than previously.

I was thinking on adding a duplicated detail section, one for Non Drop ships and other for the Drop ships, but the Visible expression i don't think will work. Even the condition is not satisfied, the processing of the subreport will happen.

Do you guys have a better idea how to handle this ?

Regards.

Comment: Can't you add the visible expression in the sub report too?

Comment: Could you share more information about the tables join conditions and parameters in your main report and subreport? In addition to Huges suggestion, if you need to limit the execution of the subreport you could add a parameter to make the query return 0 results when needed.